# Eclipse Update Conflict frequent popup

Tags: java, eclipse, popup

Every time I save my code (Ctrl + S), I get a pop-up in eclipse saying that there is an update conflict on the file system:

[image]

I am pretty sure there is no other process changing the file. Is there a way I can disable this warning in eclipse? Or does anyone know why it keeps popping up?

Comment: The last modification time of the file has changed after the editor read the file. So something it changing the file. Which editor is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe figured it out. I am saving my project to OneDrive, and I think the cloud synchronization is the reason for the pop-up.